# How To Update The Code Layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i got EditText in the Graphical Layout,

now i tried to access to `r.id.myEditTextId` from the code layout (`MainActivity.java`),
but then the compiler marked the line as syntax error.
What i have tried:

Refresh the project by F5.
Clean the project.
but it still marked as syntax error, 
what is the best way to fix it?

Edit:
the code:

```
    BB = GetButtonById(R.id.button1);//Its Working...
    BB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
               EditText TE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TE);//Here...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If this really is your code

```
r.id.myEditTextId
```

then the problem is with `r`. It should be capital

```
R.id.myEditTextId
```

If this isn't your problem then show the whole line of code where the error is.

Comment: no,i meant that the code line is: R.id.myEditTextId ... the red line is under myEditTextId

Comment: Then post the actual code and tell us what the error says. There is no other way of us knowing.

Comment: @JC1 You have to clean and **build** your project, so that the `R` file gets rebuilded with the new layout

Comment: @BackSlash do you know where i can make it automatically? (maybe in the eclipse settings)

Comment: @JC1 I don't think there is a way to do it automatically, but there should be a button somewhere to clean and build your project. I'm not familiar with Eclipse, netbeans has that button near the "run application" button

Comment: @JC1 if you were to say what the syntax error is then it would be easier to help. If its R cannot be resolved then you need to make sure you have **no** errors in **any** xml files including the `manifest`, delete R.java from gen folder then clean and run